# How can I generate a checksum for this cartridge header?

Tags: assembly, gnu, gnu-assembler, gameboy

I'm trying to generate a [cartridge header](https://gbdev.gg8.se/wiki/articles/The_Cartridge_Header) checksum for a Game Boy cart. The cartridge header checksum is defined as this C-like pseudocode:

```
unsigned char checksum = 0;
for(unsigned char *p = 0x0134; p < 0x014D; p++)
    x += ~*p;
```

or alternatively:

```
unsigned char checksum = 0;
for(unsigned char *p = 0x0134; p < 0x014D; p++)
    x = x - *p - 1;
```

This data starts at the address `0x0104`. The address `0x0134` corresponds to the beginning of `title`. The address `0x014D` corresponds to the beginning of `header_checksum`.

Note that for demonstration purposes I'm using hexadecimal escape sequences in `.ascii` strings. This won't *actually* work because `\x` isn't recognized by GNU `as`.

```
nintendo_logo:
    # Nintendo logo. Must be present and unmodified.
    .ascii "\xce\xed\x66\x66\xcc\x0d\x00\x0b\x03\x73\x00\x83\x00\x0c\x00\x0d"
    .ascii "\x00\x08\x11\x1f\x88\x89\x00\x0e\xdc\xcc\x6e\xe6\xdd\xdd\xd9\x99"
    .ascii "\xbb\xbb\x67\x63\x6e\x0e\xec\xcc\xdd\xdc\x99\x9f\xbb\xb9\x33\x3e"
title:
    # Title. At most 11 characters and zero-padded if smaller.
    # GameBoys use 16 characters.
    TITLE_SIZE = 11
    .ascii "ABCDEF"
    .fill TITLE_SIZE-(.-title)
manufacturer:
    .ascii "ABCD"
cgb_f:
    # Color Game Boy flag. 0x80 means that the game supports
    # Color Game Boy functions, but still works on the original Game Boy.
    .byte 0x80
new_licensee:
    # Company or publisher ASCII code. 00 is none.
    .ascii "00"
sgb_f:
    # Super Game Boy flag. 3 means it has support for the SGB, 0 means no.
    # I might implement color for the SGB
    .byte 0x03
cart_type:
    # Memory bank controller used and any additional hardware.
    # 0x00 is rom-only.
    .byte 0x00
rom_size:
    # ROM size in terms of 32KB << B
    .byte 0x00
ram_size:
    # The amount of externam RAM in the catridge
    .byte 0x00
is_japan:
    # If the byte is 0x00 it's for Japan, if 0x01 anywhere else
    .byte 0x01
old_licensee:
    # hex value of company/publisher
    # Super Game Boy needs 0x33 to work
    .byte 0x33
version:
    # version of the game
    .byte 0x00
header_checksum:
    # TODO: How to calculate this?
    sum = add(title, version)
    .byte sum
```

How can I calculate this checksum? If possible, is there a way to do it using assembler directives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GAS directives can't read bytes that have already been emitted into the output file.

If you wanted assemble-time *calculation* of something, I think you could do it with **a [GAS `.macro`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Macro.html) that used its arg in both an assemble-time expression updating an assembler variable, *and* as an operand for `.byte`.**

But you'd need to do it in expressions that work as numbers, which would probably rule out convenient `.ascii` string literals.

In this case it's probably more trouble than it's worth to convert over to using a macro like
`byte_cksum_accum 0xce,0xed,0x66,0x66,0xcc,0x0d,0x00, ...`.

Such a macro could maybe use `.set cksum, cksum + ~\1` or something like that, as well as `.byte \1`.  Looping over multiple GAS macro args is done by writing a recursive `.macro`.  So I think it's possible.  GAS also has a `.altmacro` syntax that allows `i = i + 1`.  I haven't used GAS macros much myself.

#### Better alternative: use a C program + build rules + `.incbin`

- Have your source use a [`.incbin "checksum_file.bin` directive](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Incbin.html)
- ... which the C program writes, after reading your `.o`
- In a Makefile, the build rule for this `.o` assembles / generates checksum externally / re-assembles to include the *right* checksum.  (touch or truncate or remove the `checksum_file.bin` before assembling the first time, whatever is most convenient to make sure it still assembles, and if necessary *doesn't* contain a stale checksum byte.)

#### Even better alternative?

- **Have your C program output a flat binary with *the data* and the checksum.**  So the header bytes are still present in exactly one place in your source, in a `uint8_t header[] = {...}` initializer in your C program.
- Use `.incbin` in the `.S` to include it.
- Use a build rule to make sure the cksummed-header.bin is an input dependency for building the `.S`

#### Or write a C program that *modifies* a binary

- Reads the header, updates a placeholder `.byte 0` in the binary file.
- Keeps the header data with the rest of the asm source
- C program doesn't need to be recompiled for different carts.

Comment: I was thinking more a C program that reads the file and writes the checksum in one go.

Comment: @S.S.Anne: that's only possible if the C program reads the asm source, not the object file (or flat binary which you create with `objcopy` or something).  Otherwise you need to assemble once to get binary input for your C program.

Comment: I was thinking that the C program can read and write the binary file for that checksum. They're all stored sequentially (per the cartridge header spec).

Comment: @S.S.Anne: ah, yes, that could work if you just leave a placeholder byte.  Or see my update: have the C program write out header + checksum for incbin.  Your idea might be even better because you can reuse the program for different cartridges.

Comment: That's odd. I used the hex escapes earlier and they inserted the literal text `\x...` in the resulting object file.

Comment: Hmm, I only tried assembling for x86 (where I do get two byte from `.ascii "\xce\xed"`), not with GAS for gameboy.  Maybe it's dependent on GAS version or target architecture?  I was assuming it wouldn't be.

Comment: It is. I'm actually using `z80-unknown-coff` (`binutils-z80` for debian). It's still odd, though.